# Using generic interface as typeparameter for a method or function

Tags: c#, type-parameter, generic-interface

Assuming the following interface which I use to define the parameter type and return type for a stored procedure...

```
public interface IStoredProcedure<out TReturn, out TParameter>
    where TReturn : class 
    where TParameter : class
{
    TReturn ReturnType { get; }

    TParameter ParameterType { get; }
}
```

...is it possible to pass this interface as a `TypeParameter` for a method? Something along the lines of this (which does not compile)

```
public static void DoAction<TProcedure>(TProcedure procedure1)
        where TProcedure : IStoredProcedure<TReturnType, TParameterType>
{
        // do some work
}
```

... or something along these lines...

```
public static void DoAction<IStoredProcedure<TReturnType, TParameterType>>(IStoredProcedure procedure1)
        where TReturnType : class
        where TParameterType : class
{
        // do some work
}
```

neither of these two methods compile, and I just cant work out how to write them to make them compile. In the `DoAction()` method I need to interogate the types of the parameters and return type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the type arguments where you specify the interface:

```
public static void DoAction<TReturnType, TParameterType>
   (IStoredProcedure<TReturnType, TParameterType> procedure1)
    where TReturnType : class
    where TParameterType : class
{
    // do some work
}
```

... otherwise you're referring to a non-generic `IStoredProcedure` interface. (Don't forget that C# allows types to be "overloaded" by generic arity.)

Comment: I'm not sure this compiles.  Shouldn't it be `DoAction<TReturnType, TParameterType>`?

Comment: @Charles: Sorry, yes. Was focusing on the parameter and didn't spot the type parameter issue. Fixed.

Comment: Yes that works now thank you, and answers alsow what would of been my next question which was how make the method into a function that returns a list of TReturnType, but that all works as well now like this..

        public List<TReturnType> GetAction<TReturnType, TParameterType>
            (IStoredProcedure<TReturnType, TParameterType> procedure1)
            where TReturnType : class
            where TParameterType : class
        {
            // do some work
            return new List<TReturnType>();
        }

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void DoAction<TProcedure, TReturnType, TParameterType>(TProcedure procedure1)
        where TProcedure : IStoredProcedure<TReturnType, TParameterType>
        where TReturnType : class
        where TParameterType : class
        {
            // do some work
        }
```

Comment: This did not compile for me.

Comment: Compiles now after your edit, but @Jon Skeet got there first with a compiling solution that fits my needs so accepted his answer. Sorry.

Comment: Also, using a type parameter for something that isn't generic is confusing and unnecessary. There are cases where it would be useful to have the `TProcedure` (e.g. if you returned `TProcedure`), but this isn't one of them.

Comment: Although I dont intend to return TProcedure, I do want the return type for a similar method to be one of the types defined by the "TReturnType" type parameter of "IStoredProcedure". I dont want to have to define the Type param in the code that calls DoAction / GetAction, rather I'd prefer to let the class that implements "IStoredProcedure" define that and then use generics to allow GetAction() to return "List<TReturnType>", if you catch my drift?